# Displaying each data line by line during AJAX CSV File Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, papaparse

I am using papaparse, Jquery AJAX, PHP and have successfully finished the parsing of csv, However, I would like to display data while my CSV file is being uploaded.

Here is a bit of my code;

```
var xhr_file = null;
$('#fileVariants').change(function(e){
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  splitFileName = file['name'].split(".");
  fileType = splitFileName.slice(-1)[0];
  if(fileType != 'csv')
  {
    $('.error-message').html('<br /><div class="notification is-warning">Only CSV file extension is allowed!</div><br />');
  }
  else
  {
    Papa.parse(file, {
      header: false,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: function(results, file) {
        file_arr = results.data;
        file_chunk = results.data;
        $('#uploadVariantsBtn').attr('disabled', false);
      }// End complete: function(results, file)
    });
  }

});
$(function(){
    $('#uploadVariants').submit(function(e){
    if($('#fileVariants').val() == '')
    {
        $('.error-message').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">File is required!</div><br />');
        return false;
    }

    var method = $(this).attr('method');
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var parameters = 'row=' + JSON.stringify(file_chunk);
    xhr_file = $.ajax({
        type : method,
        url : url,
        data : parameters,
        cache : false,
        async: false,
        dataType : "script",
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            $('#uploadVariantsBtn').attr('disabled', true);
            $('.error-message').html('<br /><div class="notification is-info has-text-centered"><img width="110" src="{{ asset("img/loading.gif") }}" title="Uploading" /></div>');
            $('.error-message').show();
            if (xhr_file != null)
            {
                xhr_file.abort();
            }
        }
    }).complete(function(data){
        $('#uploadVariantsBtn').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.error-message').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Product Variants has been updated!</div><br />');
      // $('.show-results').html('<h3>Product Variants have been updated!</h3>');
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
    });
    return false;
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

So instead of showing a progress bar in the upload, I would like to display each data line by line to show the progress.

For Example :

```
Product Data 1 has been successfully updated!
Product Data 2 has been successfully updated!
Product Data 3 already exist!
Product Data 4 has been successfully updated!
Product Data 5 has been successfully updated!
```

Is there any way to do that using PHP, Javascript, AJAX?

Comment: Do you upload data in a loop or all at once? What is your parameter value?

Answer (score 0):

You uploaded all of your data at once, then the server process your data, in completion it returns the result. You actually want the long running process's status of every single row process data.
For that, you actually need a seperate php file and ajax call. Your original php file should update the status in session or db, like below,

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['status'] = $status;
session_write_close();
```

Note that, this piece of code should be inside the loop of processing data. You should start() and close() this particular session because same session cannot be opened in other process, as we need to access this session from 2nd php file which looks like below,

```
ob_start();
session_start();
session_write_close();
$output = array();
$output['status'] = $_SESSION['status'];
echo json_encode($output);
```

Now the server side code is okay, you need to query the 2nd php with regular interval to get the processing status,

```
var timeout = setInterval('showUpdate()', 1000);
function showUpdate(){
$.get( "2ndPhp.php", function( data ) {
    var returnData = data.status;

    if (returnData.length>0){
        // This is server returned update data, you can show this or convert it to 
       //progressbar
    }

}, "json");
}
```

When you main process ends, you can close this loop by closing this interval.

```
.complete(function(data){
 clearInterval(timeout);
 $('#uploadVariantsBtn').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.error-message').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Product 
 Variants has been updated!</div><br />');
  // $('.show-results').html('<h3>Product Variants have been updated!</h3>');
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    console.log('Request failed: ' + textStatus);
});
```